# Java: Set.contains() gives wrong result

Tags: java, contains

Since Set.contains(Object o) should just use equals to check if an object is in a Set, how can the following two methods produce different results? In my project, method 1 does not throw an exception, but method 2 does throw an exception.

For information, the object "group" is in the set "groups", so Method 1 works like I would expect it.

> boolean java.util.Set.contains(Object o)
>
> > Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Method 1:

```
boolean ex = true;
for (AccessControlGroup acg : groups) {
  if ((acg.equals(group))) {
    ex = false;
  }
}
if (ex) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid group");
}
```

Method 2:

```
if (!(groups.contains(group))) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid group");
}
```

Further information:
HashSet is used.

AccessControlGroup:

```
public List<AccessControlGroup> getInherits() {

    if (this.inherits == null) {
      this.inherits = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return this.inherits;
}

public void setInherits(List<AccessControlGroup> inherits) {

    this.inherits = inherits;
}

public List<AccessControlPermission> getPermissions() {

    if (this.permissions == null) {
      this.permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return this.permissions;
}

public void setPermissions(List<AccessControlPermission> permissions) {

    this.permissions = permissions;
}

@Override 
public int hashCode() {

    final int prime = 31;
    int result = super.hashCode();
    // prevent infinity loops or other sick effects
    // result = prime * result + ((this.inherits == null) ? 0 : this.inherits.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((this.permissions == null) ? 0 : this.permissions.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((this.type == null) ? 0 : this.type.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!super.equals(obj)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    AccessControlGroup other = (AccessControlGroup) obj;
    // prevent infinity loops or other sick effects...
    // if (!Objects.equal(this.inherits, other.inherits)) {
    // return false;
    // }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.permissions, other.permissions)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.type, other.type)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
```

AccessControl:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {

    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((this.id == null) ? 0 : this.id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    AccessControl other = (AccessControl) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What `Set` implementation are you using? HashSet? TreeSet? Something else?

Comment: What is your AccessControlGroup.equals implementation?  Have you overridden it?

Comment: We need to see the implementation of the `equals()`, `hashCode()`  of `AccessControlGroup`. If it implements `Comparable` we need to see that implementation as well (and what Eran said: we need so see which Set implementation you are using)

Comment: Yep, the most likely explanation is an error in the implementation of `AccessControlGroup`, or the use of an unusual `Set` implementation like `TreeSet` or `IdentityHashSet`.

Comment: I use HashSet. I attached the code above in the entry.

Comment: The string `Set` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you've posted, so we can't actually see what you're doing.  If you're using `HashSet` as you claim, then the objects would need to correctly and consistently implement both `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll lay odds that you modified `group` after adding it to the set `groups`.  That would change its hashCode, which would leave it in the wrong bucket in `groups`, which would mean `contains` would not find it anymore unless the new hashCode happened to collide with the old one.

```
Set< AccessControlGroups > groups = new HashSet<>();
AccessControlGroup group = new AccessControlGroup();
groups.add( group );
groups.contains( group ); // true
group.setPermissions( new ArrayList<>() );
groups.contains( group ); // false
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see this happen. Actually, I printed out the hashCode of the group object as well as the hashCodes of the elements in the HashSet. The searched object in the set and the group object have the same hashCode. Even if I make the equals function of AccessControlGroup and AccessControl to always returning true regardless if the object are equal or not, contains says the object is not in the set. So maybe contains does not use this equals function? How can this happen?